# linux share (samba), how to list all shares with the path to local directory actually shared

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, share

Is there a practical way, e.g. net command or other cli to get a list of all shares defined on a Linux server (Ubuntu distribution) listing not only the share name but also the full path to the local shared directory?
Without having to look at samba config files or user shares files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cant

```
smbclient [-U ADUser] -L localhost
```

Shows the shares, but you have to look this up in your smb.conf to find the path.

ADUser is a domain User that can at least list the samba shares.

Comment: Do you have to specifiy an IP or name here, like `smbclient -L localhost` ? At least for other machines one can say `smbclient -L 10.30.40.50 -U ourdomain\\myUsrName`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.

The solution (found thanks to http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1304277&p=8186452#post8186452) is to look at the directory `/var/lib/samba/usershares` : it contains one file per share, and each file has a line starting with `path=` containing the local path

Answer (score 1):

Try this script ... feel free to improve it

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line; do
    [[ "$line" =~ ^\[ ]] && name="$line"
    [[ "$line" =~ ^[[:space:]]*path ]] && echo -e "$name\t$line"
done </etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Comment: Nice one, I'll try it. Meanwhile I guess it will miss usershares

Comment: Confirmed to miss usershares, I've improved on your script to include them

Answer (score 0):

At least two ways to do this:

##### 1. mount

```bash
$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=1959288k,nr_inodes=489822,mode=755)
...
# etc, etc
```

With no options, `mount` will list all mounted file systems. Two options are available:

- `-l` : includes labels
- `-t <type> : filters the output by filesystem <type>; e.g.` cifs`

See `man mount` for details. An example from my system:

```bash
$ mount -l -t cifs
//NetgearNAS-3/backup on /mnt/NetgearNAS/backup type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.246,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1)
//SynologyNAS-1/backups on /mnt/SynologyNAS/backups type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.1.102,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,user=seamus)
```

##### 2. findmnt

From `man findmnt`:

> findmnt  will  list  all  mounted  filesystems  or  search  for  a  filesystem.   The  findmnt  command  is able to search in /etc/fstab, /etc/mtab or /proc/self/mountinfo.  If device or mountpoint is not given, all filesystems are shown.

With no options, `findmnt` provides a neat listing of all mounted filesystems in *tree* format:

```bash
$ findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE                 FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1              ext4       rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro
├─/sys                                sysfs                  sysfs      rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/kernel/security              securityfs             securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
│ ├─/sys/fs/cgroup                    tmpfs                  tmpfs      ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755

...

# etc, etc
```

`findmnt` has an extensive set of filtering and formatting options, making it well-suited for use in scripts where the output must be parsed - see `man findmnt` for details. In this case, if we wish to restrict the output to shares (as in the smb/cifs/nfs sense), the `-t` option is handy:

```bash
$ findmnt -t cifs,nfs4
TARGET                     SOURCE                           FSTYPE OPTIONS
/mnt/SynologyNAS/rpi_share SynologyNAS-1:/volume1/rpi_share nfs4   rw,relatime,vers=4.1,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,se
/mnt/NetgearNAS-3/backup   //NetgearNAS-3/backup            cifs   rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.16
/mnt/SynologyNAS/backups   //SynologyNAS-1/backups          cifs   rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=seamus,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.
```